# Trying to share com.apollographql.apollo3 between my kmm gradle files

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kmm

Working on an Android project that has a lot of KMM modules, so I've tough I would extract a common gradle file and simply use it from the project specific gradle files.

My common gradle file is `shared-library.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
package commons

import dependencies.Dependencies
import dependencies.TestDependencies

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("com.apollographql.apollo3")
    id("com.android.library")
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Dependencies.Koin.CORE)
                implementation(Dependencies.Result.KMM)
                implementation(Dependencies.Coroutines.CORE)
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(TestDependencies.KOIN)
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = BuildAndroidConfig.COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = BuildAndroidConfig.MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdk = BuildAndroidConfig.TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    }
}
```

And then I can go use it like this from a `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
import dependencies.Dependencies

plugins {
    id("commons.shared-library")
}

....
```

This all works great except the `id("com.apollographql.apollo3")` part, when added in the shared gradle file I get the following compilation error

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Precompiled script plugin '/Users/calin/Playground/SharedAppSample/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/commons/shared-library.gradle.kts' line: 1
Plugin [id: 'com.apollographql.apollo3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

I see that the plugin is available as a gradle plugin https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=com.apollographql.apollo3

And I have `setting.gradle.kts` configured like this

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

But for some reason the KMM Gradle file will ignore this configuration (maybe?)

Comment: Is that plugin kmm compatible - seems to be JVM only? However as for the error did you include `id("com.apollographql.apollo3") version "3.5.0" apply false` in your main project `build.gradle.kts` file plugins section?

Comment: Is compatible see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/#multiplatform

Comment: Good to know - it has a "Getting started" guide why not just follow that? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/#getting-started although what I have stated above will also work fine (usually for a mutli-module projects you'd place all your plugin versions in one location, the root level build.gradle.kts file and just reference them in submodules by name only).

Answer (score 0):

The error says that it can't use the plugin repositories because no version is provided.

```
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

There are a few different ways of providing a version. Using buildSrc is my preferred way.

If `shared-library.gradle.kts` is a buildSrc convention plugin, then add a dependency using the plugins *Maven coordinates* (not the plugin ID!) in `./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`.

> The Maven coordinates are available from the Gradle plugin portal
>
> [image: Screenshot of Gradle plugin portal, highlighting the location of the plugin's Maven coordinates as classpath("com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-gradle-plugin:3.5.0")]

```kotlin
// ./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

...

dependencies {
  implementation("com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-gradle-plugin:3.5.0")
}
```

Comment: This does not really solve the problem as it adds the plugin to the android gradle files not to the kmm ones

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The plugin will only be added when it is declared in a `plugins {}` block - and that's unrelated to whether the plugin is added as a dependency in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the version after the apollo plugin id

```
plugins {
  kotlin("multiplatform")
  kotlin("native.cocoapods")
  id("com.apollographql.apollo3").version("3.6.2")
  id("com.android.library")
}
```

Make sure the version matches the apollo-runtime version in dependencies, if you have it.